# Center and crop img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, center

Just wondering is it possible to use

```
<div><img src="xxx.jpg" /></div>
```

1. to center the image in the browser
2. List item to maintain it in the center when reduce browser width for responsive layout
3. when browser with is smaller than the image it will "not" reduce the image size
4. instead it will crop the image (overflow:hidden) with the scrollbar but still maintain the image center...

is it possible for using img tag to do this?? I know I can perform it easily with background image using css.

but since I'm working on a CMS site and the image is uploaded by client side, so background image is definitely not a solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think point 3 and 4 make it impossible to do this with CSS only as you would have to set the scroll position using CSS, the best I can come up with using CSS only is: <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2ppS/1/)</kbd> and a <kbd>[**Fullscreen Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2ppS/1/embedded/result/)</kbd>.

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
div {
    max-width: 100%;
}
img {
    margin: 0 -100% 0 -100%;
}
```

This approach keeps the image in the center at all times, and it kind of doesn't really reduce the image size, but because I've had to use negative margins, you can't scroll the invisible parts into view.

Instead going for a JS approach you could do it this way: <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9aA9G/1/)</kbd> and a <kbd>[**Fullscreen Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9aA9G/1/embedded/result/)</kbd>.

**CSS**

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("div").scrollLeft(($("img").width() / 2) - ($(this).width() / 2))
});
```

This approach uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to ensure the center of the image scrolls into view whenever the browser window is re-sized.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, actually you have almost answer all my question though, the scroll isn't really a bid deal just something extra i asked for. =)

Comment: but can you explain to me the logic behind, how does setting img -100% and body text-align center to center the image? and is div max-width=100% necessary?

Comment: `body {text-align: center}` centers the `div` on the page, setting the negative margins on both sides ensures that both sides are equally as hungry to try and eat up the overflow space when the containing elements size decreases, setting `max-width: 100%;` on the `div` ensures that the `div` decreases in width when the browser window is re-sized to a width smaller than the `div`'s original width (which is set by its content, as the original value for the width on the `div` is `auto`).